# How block user from creating Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-identity

Currently users from our organization able to create free Azure trial, pay as you go and Azure student subscription, which makes a lot subscriptions in our tenant.

We want to disable the users from creating these subscriptions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How block user from creating Azure Subscription

If you want to prevent a user from creating an `Azure subscription` in `Azure AD` tenant, you can use below `PowerShell` script to disable **AllowSelfServicePurchase** for all products. but users won't be able to renew their trial accounts when **AllowSelfServicePurchase** is **$false**.

```
    Install-Module -Name MSCommerce -force
    Import-Module -Name MSCommerce  
    Connect-MSCommerce 
    $products = Get-MSCommerceProductPolicies -PolicyId AllowSelfServicePurchase | Where { $_.PolicyValue -eq "Enabled"}
    foreach ($p in $products){
    Update-MSCommerceProductPolicy -PolicyId AllowSelfServicePurchase -ProductId $p.ProductId -Enabled $False
    }
```

**Response:**

[image]

Refer **Disable AllowSelfServicePurchase**  on [Q&A](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/disable-allowselfservicepurchase-mscommerceproductpolicy/m-p/3935163) by @ `LeonPavesic`

[Prevent standard users from creating subscriptions in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/701756/prevent-standard-users-from-creating-subscriptions) by `Marilee Turscak-MSFT`

Comment: It doesn't blocking user from creating free trial, pay as you go, Azure student subscriptions

Comment: Make sure to disable all product using above PowerShell script and wait for same time to sync the settings, for more details refer the above Link.

Comment: yes i have disabled all products and tried after 1hour, still  it is not  blocking user from creating free trial, pay as you go, Azure student subscriptions

Comment: hi @Venkat V , still it is not blocking user from creating free trial, pay as you go, Azure student subscriptions. can you please help me on this