# How block user from creating Azure Subscription in AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory

Currently users from our organization able to create free Azure trial, pay as you go and Azure student subscription, which makes a lot subscriptions in our tenant.

We want to disable the users from creating these subscriptions [reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMq7K.png)

Posted [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77691768/how-block-user-from-creating-azure-subscription) but doesn't answer my question. Can someone help me on this

Comment: Check if these helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/682675/block-trial-subscriptions-being-created-in-tenant and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/701756/prevent-standard-users-from-creating-subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an option that completely restricts users from creating all types of subscriptions. You can use Powershell and set "[AllowAdHocSubscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msolcompanysettings?view=azureadps-1.0#parameters)" to "false" to prevent the creation of trial subscriptions, but there are still certain trial sign-ups such as Flow and Powerapps that are not controlled by the AllowAdHocSubscriptions flag

Another option is to use elevated access to manage all subscriptions in your directory.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin

If you have an EA agreement there is an option to create a support ticket to block non-EA subscription sign up subscription sign-up for free trial, Pay-As-You-Go, and some other subscriptions from an EA tenant.